# One menu for frontpage (one pager), and a different menu for posts

Tags: posts, menus, navigation

*(TLDR version at the end)*

I have set up a website for a company who wanted a "one page" website. This is delievered and done. My main menu consists purely of #anchor tags.

They have now started sending out newsletters, and they link from the newsletter to posts on their website. Problem now is that the main menu doesnt work on posts, as its anchor tags. First I tried changing the menu, example:
From #aboutus
To http://websiteurl.com/#aboutus

This works, but when using the navigation on the frontpage it has a major drawback - the scrolling doesnt work. Instead the browser will simply reload the entire site, and put the user on the selected anchor.

So my thought right now is that I need to have a separate menu for all subpages(posts). I cant seem to find out how to make this happen. A criteria when making the website was that I was not allowed to hard code / custom code anything. They wanted it entirely built up via plugins/themes and native functions in Wordpress.

**TLDR: Is it possible to set one menu for the front page - and another menu for all posts?**

Comment: If you aren't allowed to code your own plugin or theme, then you're probably stuck unless you can find a plugin that does this for you.  Plugin recommendations are off-topic here though.

Comment: did you check the theme menu options really carefully?  If a designed well, it should accommodate additional pages and handle the navigation modifications correctly.

Comment: I have, and I've contacted the company behind the theme (Artbees, theme: Jupiter) and asked them about this. No good answer has come yet though.